# ''CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command' error while trying to add it to package.json>build script in React

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vercel

I have project and I wanted to deploy it to Vercel. When I first tried to deploy, it said

> Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true

After I see this, I added **CI=false &&** to the build script and builded it. But this time another error occured

> 'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Where am I doing wrong guys? There's anyone who can help me to get rid of it?

**package.json>"scripts:"**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change as below:

```
"build": "set CI=false && react-scripts build",
```